# java giving me 15 numbers instead of 14 in random number generator

Tags: java, random

I am trying to generate random numbers for the cards in a deck(2-14) however, when I run the program, I sometimes get 15. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
    dealer1= (int) (Math.random() *14+2);
    dealer2= (int) (Math.random () *14+2);
    player1= (int) (Math.random () *14+2);
    player2= (int) (Math.random () *14+2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` returns a value between 0.0 (inclusive) and 1.0 (exclusive).

Say we roll 0.99, so we get 13,86. So 15,86. Rounded to int, that's 15.

Please consider using [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) instead, it has a method `nextInt(arg)` that returns random values in `0..arg-1`:

```
Random random = new Random(); // preferably private, static, final, shared across your application
int dealer1 = random.nextInt(13) + 2;
int dealer2 = random.nextInt(13) + 2;
int player1 = random.nextInt(13) + 2;
int player2 = random.nextInt(13) + 2;
```

Comment: Or even better `SecureRandom.nextInt(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you convert a floating point number to an integer it rounds down (it gets floored).

Let's say your `Math.random() * 14` returns `13.9`
In your example you add 2 to your result, therefore the value is now `13.9 + 2 = 15.9`
Once all the operations are completed, the value is rounded down by the cast to an int.

This final rounding down is why you are ending up with a 15 sometimes, as 15.9 rounded down is 15.

This example should help you understand what's happening:
https://repl.it/NjUT